# why i am getting previous id during dropdown

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a block with many small blocks inside. I want to edit those small blocks and save all at once. So when I click edit I have a popup form which when submitted with required data will give me fresh data. Now problem is when I edit 1st block and then move on to edit 2nd block after submit click the dropdown still give me previous id instead of new one. Where I am doing wrong? I just can't get it. I also tried to remove selected attribute after each submit

```
$('#overlay_form').find('select.getdata option:selected').attr('selected', '');
```

My code is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/samjhana/AbyLN/3/

any help or suggesstions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to simplify this

**On Change Event of Drop down List**

```
$('select.getdata').change(function(){

 var id= $(this).val();
 if(id==1)
 {
    // here is your code 
 }
 else if(id==2)
 {
   //here is your code
 }     

});

 $('a#btn_getdata').click(function(){

 var id= $('select.getdata').val();
 if(id==1)
 {
    // here is your code 
 }
 else if(id==2)
 {
   //here is your code
 }     

});
```

Comment: thanks your solution help me solve it but why my code didn't work.

Comment: an error in this code is the var id= $(this).val(); inside the $('a#btn_getdata').click block. You are supposed to fetch the value of the select button. Here the value of the button will be displayed instead. id should be set to global outside of the two functions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your fiddle, you will have to make the variable controllerID global or at least shared by the two events.

```
var controllerId;

$('select.getdata').live('change', function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
...
```

The click event of GetData X should not be inside the change event.

```
   $('a.ok').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    e.stopPropagation();
                    alert(controllerId);
...
```

Here is an update to your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AbyLN/4/

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are binding multiple events to the 
    "GetData" Link

```
 $('a#btn_getdata').click(function(){
      e.preventDefault();
      var pos = $('input.position').val();
      var url = $('input[name=url]').val();
  });
  //and 
  $('a.ok').click(function(){
  });
```

The click events are getting added to the same a tag. Try rewriting your code so that u have all your logic inside

```
 $('a.ok').on('click', function(){
 });
```

Also note that as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. If you need to bind events to non-existent html nodes that will appear later via ajax, you can do so like this

```
$('document').on('click', 'a.ok', function(){
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't help but i got to know something new. Any other options .

Comment: To me, it looks like your approach is what seems to be causing the problem. You need to bind single event handler to your main submit button. Then in it, you need to check what value of dropdown is selected and handle form submission accordingly. Best luck.